# Valueless Column Technique in Cassandra - Database Schema

Tags: hyperlink, cassandra, database-schema, schema-design

I'm using Cassandra 0.8.2

I am attempting to use the "valueless column" technique to set up my cassandra schema. The idea behind the valueless column is the following: The name of your column becomes the relevant information & the value of the "name/value" pair is empty. This is used to make queries faster - an example of denormalization. I want the name of the column to be the url of the back link. The row key is be a UUID of the target url of the back link. Is this even a good idea/schema design?

I'm using a very basic example to get the point of my question across. Here's what I have set up using the Cassandra-Cli:

```
create column family ArticleBackLinks 
with comparator = UTF8Type
and key_validation_class = UTF8Type
and default_validation_class = UTF8Type
and column_metadata = 
[
{column_name: www.arstechnica.com, validation_class: UTF8Type},        
{column_name: www.apple.com, validation_class:UTF8Type},         
{column_name: www.cnn.com, validation_class: UTF8Type},      
{column_name: www.stackoverflow.com, validation_class: UTF8Type}, 
{column_name: www.reddit.com, validation_class: UTF8Type}
];
```

I get the error:

```
Command not found: `create column family ArticleBackLink...
```

I think my error is due to the period I am using in the column_name. In short, I would like to know if some of you have come across better ways to use the "valueless column" idea in Cassandra? Any good/better examples of the valueless column technique? Is my idea even the right way to use the valueless column technique?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Cassandra does not like the `dot` in `column_name`, the following works

```
[default@stackoverflow] create column family ArticleBackLinks with
...     comparator = UTF8Type and
...     default_validation_class = UTF8Type and
...     column_metadata =
...     [
...     {column_name: 'www.arstechnica.com', validation_class: UTF8Type},
...     {column_name: 'www.apple.com', validation_class:UTF8Type},
...     {column_name: 'www.cnn.com', validation_class: UTF8Type},
...     {column_name: 'www.stackoverflow.com', validation_class: UTF8Type},
...     {column_name: 'www.reddit.com', validation_class: UTF8Type}
...     ];
881b31f0-bc64-11e0-0000-242d50cf1ff7
Waiting for schema agreement...
... schemas agree across the cluster
```

---

By the way, since you are using Cassandra 0.8.2 you should leverage CQL

So, statement like this will be helpful in future

```
UPDATE <COLUMN FAMILY> [USING <CONSISTENCY> 
[AND TIMESTAMP <timestamp>] [AND TTL <timeToLive>]] 
SET name1 = value1, name2 = value2 WHERE <KEY> = keyname;
```

Refer [this](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/doc/cql/CQL.textile)

---

**updated:** *added more thoughts as comment asked*

It's a good idea to keep grouped information at one place. It adds on efficiency that Cassandra provides.

For example, your case can have `category` as RowKey and urls be `column_name`. So, on your front end, you can display categorized view quickly, because you know that `arstechnicia` and `stackoverflow` comes under `technology` group which is a rowKey. It adds a tiny bit of extra work when you insert data.

I use Cassandra 0.6.x, so sadly I can't tell a lot about secondary index that Cassandra 0.7.0+ supports. But supposedly, you can achieve what explained above by adding a column say, `category`, in the main CF whose index is held by `ArticleBackLink` and just query using CQL's `select... where...`.

You might look into secondary index that might vanish the need of having a new 'index CF`. You may want to look into these:

- [Secondary Index in Cassandra 0.7](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-cassandra-07-secondary-indexes)
- [Cassandra Wiki FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/SecondaryIndexes)

> **Q:** Is there a difference between creating a secondary index vs creating an "index" CF manually such as "users_by_country"?
>
> **A:** Yes. First, when creating your own index, a node may index data held by another node. Second, updates to the index and data are not atomic.

Comment: While working with Cassandra, what are your thoughts on using "valueless columns" as a technique to denormalize data?